# how do you convert a txt file into a data frame in R

Tags: r, parsing

I have a .txt file like this:

```
<begin>
pwd
cd ~
<end>
<begin>
ls
vi
<end>
<begin>
cat
ls
pwd
<end>
```

etc
I need to create a data frame from this text file. The code between  and  goes into the data frame.

For example, above data should represented in data frame as follows:

```
user1 pwd
user1 cd~
user2 ls
user2 vi
user3 cat
user3 ls
user3 pwd
```

etc

how would I do this in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

Import your data:

```
dat <- readLines(textConnection("<begin>
pwd
cd ~
<end>
<begin>
ls
vi
<end>
<begin>
cat
ls
pwd
<end>"))
```

Then get your result:

```
result <- data.frame(user=cumsum(dat=="<begin>"),dat)
result[!result$dat %in% c("<begin>","<end>"),]

#   user  dat
#2     1  pwd
#3     1 cd ~
#6     2   ls
#7     2   vi
#10    3  cat
#11    3   ls
#12    3  pwd
```